# GtkCellRendererPixbuf and signals

Tags: c, gtk

Could anyone please give me a hint on how to attach a "double clicked" signal
to the pixbuf that is in the GtkTreeView? GtkCellRendererPixbuf
doesn't have any signals?

I managed to set the GTK_CELL_RENDERER_MODE_ACTIVATABLE switch to the
renderer, but I don't know how to work.
I checked the header file and in fact there is the "activate" method; could you please
demonstrate how to use it?

```
renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new();
g_object_set(renderer, "mode", GTK_CELL_RENDERER_MODE_ACTIVATABLE, NULL);
column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes(NULL,
                                                      renderer,
                                                      "pixbuf",
                                                      0,
                                                      NULL);
gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view), column);
```

OK I try this:

Tree view's 'row-activated' will send the path and column as arguments
to the callback. With 'cursor-changed' just need to call
    gtk_gtk_treeview_get_cursor to find out the path and column. With
gtk Widget's 'button-press-event' I get the event as an argument for
the callback and just need to call gtk_treeview_get_path_at_pos with
event x and event y to get the path and column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cell renderer is only supposed to draw the contents of the data model over a portion of the widget. Interaction with the user is in most cases realized using the widget itself.

In other words, simply connect to the `button-press-event` of the tree view and handle the case when the type is `GDK_2BUTTON_PRESS`. You can get the row/column under the mouse using `gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos`, as you do in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27204006/1600898).

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
void on_treeview_row_activated(GtkTreeView *treeview, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *col, gpointer data)
{
    GtkTreeModel *model;
    GtkTreeIter   iter;

    model = gtk_tree_view_get_model( treeview );

    if ( gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &iter, path) )
    {

        gtk_tree_model_get(model, &iter, 
                    ITEM, &dhd_contaItem2,
                            CODIGO, &dhd_G_CodProduto2 ,
                            DESCRICAO, &dhd_G_NomeProduto2 ,
                            QTD, &dhd_quantidade2,
                            VALOR, &dhd_valorItem2,
                           -1);
        g_print( "Current row: %s %s %s %s %s\n", dhd_contaItem2, dhd_G_CodProduto2, dhd_G_NomeProduto2,    dhd_quantidade2, dhd_valorItem2  );

    }


}
```

I use that in one of my codes to print in terminal the selected row from a TreeView (with ListStore) when double clicked or when you press enter on it. On the `gtk_tree_model_get` notice that I'm using my own columns and variables, as i do in `g_print`. And I attach this function with row-activated signal on the TreeView. I don't know if is that what you want exactly but I hope it helps you out. Sorry for my bad english.