# Context Menus on Right Click in GtkTreeView (only for specified column)

Tags: gtk

I want to show a popup menu if 'right click' in a row from GtkTreeView.
It is possible that the popup menu shows up only if 'right click' in first column (or specificate column)?

I have use code but this sown up menu for entire row.

```
gboolean
on_tree_view_button_pressed(GtkWidget *treeview, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer data)
{

    if (event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS && event->button == 3) {
        GtkTreePath *path;

        selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview));
        if (gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview),
                                                      event->x, event->y,
                                              &path, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        gtk_tree_selection_unselect_all(selection);
        gtk_tree_selection_select_path(selection, path);
        gtk_tree_path_free(path);
        }

        do_popup_menu(treeview, event, data);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I have GtkTreeView with 3 columns and I want to show up menu only for first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already calling `gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos`. This function can also obtain the treeview column under the mouse. Instead of passing NULL for the `column` argument, make sure to get the column and compare it to your desired column:

```
if (event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS && event->button == 3) {
    GtkTreePath *path;
    GtkTreeViewColumn *column;

    selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview));
    if (!gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview),
                                       event->x, event->y,
                                       &path, &column, NULL, NULL))
        // if we can't find path at pos, we surely don't
        // want to pop up the menu
        return FALSE;

    if (column != gtk_tree_view_get_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), 0)) {
        // wrong column, don't bother
        gtk_tree_path_free(path);
        return FALSE;
    }

    gtk_tree_selection_unselect_all(selection);
    gtk_tree_selection_select_path(selection, path);
    gtk_tree_path_free(path);

    do_popup_menu(treeview, event, data);

    return TRUE;
}
```